# Google cloud functions only working on development - functions returned undefined, expected Promise or value

Tags: javascript, promise, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want this to work on deploy. It does what its meant to do in local development, add a bunch of drugstores to a `Firestore` database. It also deploys successfully, and it even returns `success` on google cloud platform when I trigger it.

**BUT** it doesn't do anything when triggered from **google cloud platform**. Like i said, only works on development.

The only hint I have is what I get logged in the terminal when I ran it on develop.

```
firebase > getFarmacias()
'Successfully invoked function.'
firebase > info: User function triggered, starting execution
error: Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value
info: Execution took 20 ms, user function completed successfully
```

Here is the code of my function.

```
exports.getFarmacias = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 20 * * *').onRun((context) => {
  // Declare http requests
  const firstReq = axios.get('https://farmanet.minsal.cl/maps/index.php/ws/getLocalesTurnos')
  const secondReq = axios.get('https://farmanet.minsal.cl/maps/index.php/ws/getLocalesUrgencia')

  // Trigger both requests with axios.all
  axios.all([firstReq, secondReq]).then(axios.spread((turno, urgencia) => {
    const farmacias = [...turno.data, ...urgencia.data];

    // for each element in 'farmacias' add a new document to 'firestore/farmacias'
    farmacias.forEach(farmacia => {
      return db.collection('farmacias').add({ farmacia })
      })
  })).catch(err=> console.log(err));
})
```

I've read other answers and try to return every line in the code, but I can't get it right.

Comment: You need to return a promise that resolves only after all the async work is complete.  If you don't do that, Cloud Functions may shut down all of that work, and it will never complete.  This behavior is not emulated locally.

Comment: Do you know where is the error in my code, Doug? I “promise” I’ll study fundamentals l8r I need this done 